# Pepper Android Tablet not detected by Android Studio

Tags: windows, pepper

I have installed the Pepper SDK for the Android Studio and created a basic App for Pepper. I am able to run the App in the Android Emulator. However, My Android Studio is not detecting the Pepper Tablet.

Several things I have already tried:
1. Enabled the developer options on the Pepper tablet for USB Debugging.
2. Installed ADB to see if ADB detects the Tablet but it doesn't. Although both my laptop and the Pepper are on the same WIFI.

I'm using Android 2.3.3 . Anyone knows how to make the Android Studio detect the Pepper Tablet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android version of the Pepper SDK has only been released on the emulator for now. Stay tuned for the software release on your Pepper !

Just be aware that this new version will *not* be compatible with Choregraphe and Python anymore, and you won't be able to switch back and forth between "pepper with python" and "pepper with android".

Comment: Thanks for the update. That helps a lot. So, If I code on Choregraphe and Javascript as of now, Will it be compatible with the future updates of Pepper? Doesn't the new version support Choregraphe at all?

Comment: They are different versions. So no, there will be no support for chorégraphe in the Android version.

Answer (score 0):

What version of NAOqi is installed on your Pepper? If it's 2.5 or below, the Android SDK won't work.

You also need to have a recent enough hardware model, 1.8a or 1.8 (see [here](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/family/pepper_technical/pepper_versions.html), but basically, the tablet should have a camera near the top border)

Comment: The Naoqi version is 2.5.7.1. Android Studio is still not detecting the Pepper Tablet. Any suggestions/workarounds?

Comment: No, in any 2.5.* versions, you won't be able to connect to the tablet. The new Android QiSDK is only for Pepper 1.8 / 1.8a and above, with NAOqi  2.7 or above.

Comment: I'm confused. I see NAOqi OS 2.8.2 for NAO V6 Robot. However, In the Aldebaran community Software, If I tick on the Pepper in 'My Robots' menu. I see that the latest version for Pepper is just 2.5.5.  Am I missing something here? Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: NAOqi 2.8 is indeed only for Nao; NAOqi 2.7 (on which the Android SDK works) has not been publicly released yet.

Comment: Oh. So, are you suggesting that I cannot use the Tablet on the pepper as of now? Is there a way I can get the alpha/beta release?

Comment: The tablet can be used, the usual way to do so is to package a webpage in your application and use the javascript SDK on it; it's also technically possible to make Android applications that use the old Java SDK, but that's not recommended (and you still won't be able to connect to the tablet with android studio etc. like you can with the new Pepper Android SDK).

Comment: Thank you. That helps a lot. :) I'm able to use the tablet with JavaScript now.  I Have a question, I am reading the javascript SDK and I am going through 'Using Services' section. It mentions that Javascript calls are completely asynchronous 
 ( http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-4/dev/js/index.html ). I want to code a scenario where I first say I am doing the elephant Animation and then do the elephant animation. It is possible with the Android SDK. Is it possible to do it with Javascript SDK too?

Comment: Sure, by doing something like `TTS.say("elephant").then(do_animation)`...